# Unable to click on google's search result through selenium web driver (Java)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to search some thing on google, lets say "Testing". So I want to click on 1st search result, but unable to do that. Please find my code below. I have tried with xpath, class and cssSelector. Please help.:

```
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");

    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Testing" + Keys.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(5);

    driver.findElement(
            By.className("r"))
            .click();
}
```

Please find the Inspect Element result as well:

Software testing - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia

Comment: <a href="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;q=&amp;esrc=s&amp;source=web&amp;cd=1&amp;cad=rja&amp;uact=8&amp;ved=0ahUKEwio74agy-3OAhVEppQKHaZfA78QFggcMAA&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSoftware_testing&amp;usg=AFQjCNEIb84acEmEpi0D-2VeAq4wvejpkQ&amp;bvm=bv.131286987,d.dGo" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNEIb84acEmEpi0D-2VeAq4wvejpkQ','','0ahUKEwio74agy-3OAhVEppQKHaZfA78QFggcMAA','','',event)" data-href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing">Software testing - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</a>

Comment: above is my Inspect Element result

Comment: What is happening when you run the code? Its running perfectly alright in my machine. Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element is visible and enable to click as below :-

```
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");

driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Testing" + Keys.ENTER);

new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By
                        .linkText("Software testing - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try once giving location of link instead of header

```
xpath= //h3[@class='r']/a
```

if you are going to click on first link only, then above path work.

If you want to click on specific element, then try to build xpath which return specific element. For example to click on wikipedia link

```
xapth=//a[@href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing']
```

You can also try like

```
1.collecting all links into List and 
2. iterating one by one
3. By using getText get text and verify required one
4. once condition satisfy then click on it.
```